# get the difference in time between two given time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the difference in time between two given times e.g. first time '17:00:01' and then second time '17:47:25' and here's what I tried so far,

```
$start_time = "17:00:01";
$end_time = "17:47:25";

echo $start_time->diff($end_time);
```

But seem's unfortunately not working, any help, ideas please?

My expected output must be like, if no difference in hours but there's difference in minutes and seconds then, "22 mins and 15 secs", If no difference in minutes but have difference in hours then, "2 hrs and 10 secs" but if only seconds in difference then, "22 secs".

Comment: you need to custom code for it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php but your example is missing the initialization.

Comment: what result are you getting?  Have you tried adding a date in front of the times? Have you tried using the `Date()` function for formatting the result?  Have you tried using the DateTime class?

Comment: I got 'diff is not an object' and later I realized that the date must be converted to object first so I use 'new DateTime' for every retrieved date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String in php is not object, so can't call `diff` method on it.

Use `diff` method, you must change the string to `DateTime` object.

If you want to compare time difference in same day, you could try:

```
$start_time = "17:00:01";
$end_time = "17:47:25";

$start_datetime = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$start_time);
$end_datetime = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$end_time);

var_dump($start_datetime->diff($end_datetime));
```

Comment: yeah right that's it, I need to make it unto an object first

Answer (score 3):

Get difference between two times

```
 public function convTimeToMinutes($intime, $outtime)
    {
            $start = Carbon::parse($intime);
            $end = Carbon::parse($outtime);
            $minutes = $end->diffInMinutes($start); // 226
            return $this->convertMinuteToHours($minutes);  
    } 

public function convertMinuteToHours($minutes)
    {
        return $minutes / 60;
    }

$totalHour = $this->convTimeToMinutes('09:25:35', '13:12:27');
//$totalHour = 3.76
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is it.

**PHP**

```
$start_time = "17:00:01";
$end_time = "17:47:25";

$time1 = new DateTime($start_time);
$time2 = new DateTime($end_time);
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $hour = $interval->format('%h hour');
echo $min = $interval->format('%i min');
echo $sec = $interval->format('%s second');
```

**Output:**

```
0 hour 47 min 24 sec
```

Now you can add some condition and make the real format.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of doing it using string functions:

```
/*
 * Get difference in seconds between time formats
 */
function getDiff($start_time, $end_time)
{
    $start_time = timeFormatToSeconds($start_time);
    $end_time = timeFormatToSeconds($end_time);

    if ($end_time > $start_time) {
        return $end_time - $start_time;
    }

    return false;
}

/*
 * Convert time format (HH:MM:SS) to seconds
 */
function timeFormatToSeconds($time_format)
{
    sscanf($time_format, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

    return $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

$start_time = "17:00:01";
$end_time = "17:47:25";

$diff = getDiff($start_time, $end_time);

if ($diff) {
    $hours = floor($time / (60 * 60));
    $time -= $hours * (60 * 60);

    $minutes = floor($time / 60);
    $time -= $minutes * 60;

    $seconds = floor($time);
    $time -= $seconds;

    var_dump(array($hours, $minutes, $seconds));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert string time to timestamp and subtract. Convert timestamp to desired time format.

```
$start_time = strtotime('17:00:01');
$end_time = strtotime('17:47:25');
$diff = $end_time - $start_time;
echo date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as a generic function

```
private function calculateDiffInMinutes($from, $to)
{
    $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $from);
    $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $to);
    return $to->diffInMinutes($from);
}
```

and you can call the function anywhere and pass the parameters you need 
here the difference between now and created at time

```
$this->calculateDiffInMinutes($item->created_at, now())
```

Hope this helped